# Need some help in writing an essay about education as the main goal in life

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, word-usage

*Good afternoon everyone! Can you kindly help me with these sentences (I really don't know if natives do write this way about the priority in life (which for me is education).*

For some people money is the main priority in life, while **I consider my education as the main aim**. I am ready to spend my money on studying to get an interesting and well-paid job in the future.

So, **for me**, it is necessary to contribute in studying now to achieve success later. A little help is very important too. That's when family support matters! Family or friends can help in collecting the information required or simply in preparing meals. **When there is no time, a help like this is priceless.**

**To me,** an ideal study room should be spacious and uncluttered. I try to organize my workplace so I can work efficiently and focus on my studying.

*P.S. The bold parts of the sentences are the ones that I am totally unsure about. I would be very grateful for any comments on this)*

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that we are not a proofreading service, though we can help you work through specific questions about grammar or usage— why do you think your sentences would not be appropriate? What research have you done? I encourage you to take the site [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) center for additional guidance.

Comment: Alas, this site is not set up for general criticism and proofreading.  In any case, without the context, it's impossible to give cogent advice on written work.  There's nothing wrong with your grammar.  I've fixed some punctuation and the distracting (lack of ) spacing, but unless you have specific questions on the parts in bold, your question is likely to be closed.  By the way, I am not the downvoter.

Comment: Thank you for your response!I just need to write an essay on the topic "What specific things you can do for your goal?".These are the sentences from my finished essay which I consider is full of sentences natives don't ever use.I am just unsure if someone speaks or writes this way.

Comment: Besides other corrections being provided in answers, I would use "objective" instead of "aim" and "such help" instead of "a help like this".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, in general, proofreading questions are off-topic in this forum. However, since you have identified a couple of phrases in bold, I will speak to a couple of things that may prove helpful:

- I consider my education **to be** my main aim
- "help" not "a help"
- nothing wrong with your use of "for me"/"to me"

Comment: thank you very much!And what about the sentence "When there is no time,  help like this is priceless.".I am confused because I never ever heard anyone saying this so I don't know if it is correct and right to write it.Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's grammatical, but I agree with you that it's nonstandard. The issue (in my opinion) is that "when there is no time" is too general to pair with the specific phrase "help like this is priceless." You want the two parts to be of equivalent specificity. So you might try: "For those with little or no spare time, help like this is priceless." Or even: "When people have no time, help like this is priceless."

Comment: You might also try to bring the comment back to your personal situation. For example: "Because my studies provide me little free time, help like this is priceless." Or: "When the demands of my studies mean I have no time for other activities, help like this is priceless."